# The preimage $\phi^{-1}\{H\}$ of a subgroup $H$ of a factor group $G\big /N$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$, furthermore, let $H$ be a subgroup of the factor group $G\big /N$. Denote by $\phi:G \rightarrow G\big/N$ the canonical homomorphism: $g\mapsto gN$. The problem is to show that $\phi^
{-1}\{H\} = \{g\in G: \phi(g)\in H\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

We need to show the following properties of the set $\phi^{-1}\{H\}$:

- $e \in \phi^{-1}\{H\}$
- If $x_1, x_2\in \phi^{-1}\{H\}$ then $x_1x_2 \in \phi^{-1}\{H\}$
- $\forall x\in \phi^{-1}\{H\} \exists x^{-1}\in\phi^{-1}\{H\}: xx^{-1}=e=x^{-1}x$

Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G\big/N$ it is immediately clear that: $N=\phi(e)\in H$ so $e \in \phi^{-1}\{H\}$.

Furthermore, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in $\phi^{-1}\{H\}$ then both $\phi(x_1)$ and $\phi(x_2)$ are in $H$, since $H$ is already a subgroup we have:
$\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2) = \phi(x_1x_2)\in H$, so $x_1x_2\in \phi^{-1}\{H\}$.

It is the last part that has me confused; suppose $x\in \phi^{-1}\{H\}$, then since $H$ is a subgroup we have:
$\phi(e) = \phi(x)[\phi(x)]^{-1}$, let $g\in G$ be such that $\phi(g) = [\phi(x)]^{-1}$, then
$\phi(e) = \phi(x)\phi(g) = \phi(xg)$, so the inverse coset of $xN$ is $gN$, can I immediately draw the conclusion that $g = x^{-1}$ ?

My idea was the following:

Since $xNgN = xgN = eN$ then for any $n\in N$ we have: $xgn = n \Leftrightarrow xgnn^{-1} = nn^{-1} \Leftrightarrow xg = e$ so $g$ must be $x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you always have to show that the subgroup is **closed** under the group operation. Then the easiest way to show that $G' \neq \emptyset$ is a subgroup of $G$ is to show $a,b \in G'\Rightarrow ab^{-1} \in G'$, which is an equivalent criterion of being a subgroup. Clearly $\phi$ is a homomorphism of groups and the inverse image of a group under a homomorphism $\phi$ is **always** a group itself. 
 Concerning your question: You are right choosing $x^{-1}N$ as the inverse of $xN$. By definition of the factor group: $x^{-1}NxN=N$ and uniqueness of inverse proves the claim.

Comment: The problem is to show that the preimage is a subgroup, so to say that it always is so will not help me. However, the alternative criterion does give some new perspective.